# can someone help me to find minimum expenditure in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written the below Python code to find the total and minimum expenditures. However, when I execute this code, the minimum expenditure only returns zero, while the maximum and total expenditures are working perfectly.

```
exp =-1
total=0
maxexp=0
minexp=`0

while exp!=0:

    exp = int(input("enter your expenditure: "))
    total= total + exp

    if exp < minexp:
        minexp = exp

print("`Total `expenditure is: " + str(total))
print("your minimum expenditure is: " + str(minexp))
```

[image]

Comment: 0 is smaller than all the numbers you entered. Either initialize the value with a large value or explicitly check for a 0 when comparing the current against the min.

Comment: You might want to put all the inputs in a list. Then you can use the `sum` and `min` functions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep track of the minimum amount you should initialise *minexp* to an artificially high number:

```
total = 0
minexp = float('inf')

while (exp := int(input('enter your expenditure (0 to quit): '))) != 0:
    total += exp
    minexp = min(exp, minexp)

if total:
    print(f'Total expenditure is {total}')
    print(f'minimum expenditure is {minexp}')
```